# Uncheck checkboxes in html and css only?

Tags: html, css, image, checkbox, radio-button

I've been trying to create something similar to google images (when you click on an image it 'opens' a larger version with information and links and when you click again it closes).

My task (school) is to realise this with only pure html(5) and css(3), so no javascript or JQuery or any other programming language.

I already tried using checkboxes and radio. When I use checkboxes, it will expand an 'informationbox' which will not close when I open the next one. There only needs to be one open at a time.
Therefore I also tried using radio. The problem here is that I'm not able to deselect them.

Is it possible to realise this with only html and css?

Is there anyone who can help me?

Thanks in advance!

```css
.folder {
 width: 100%;
 visibility: hidden;
}

.fold {
 visibility: hidden;
 background-color: #8b0000;
 width: 60%;
 height: 0px;
 color: transparent;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 position: absolute;
}

.toggle { display: none; }

.toggle-label {
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: #999;
 background-color: #8b0000;
 padding: 5px;
}

.toggle-label:hover {
 background-color: #400000;
}

.toggle:checked ~ .fold {
 height: 80px;
 visibility: visible;
 color: #fff;
}

.content{
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 0;
 position: static;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

.toggle:checked ~ .content {
 min-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<label for="toggle1" class="toggle-label">FOLD/UNFOLD</label>
   <label for="toggle2" class="toggle-label">FOLD/UNFOLD</label>
   <label for="toggle3" class="toggle-label">CLOSE</label>
   <div class="content">
    <aside class="folder">
     <input type="checkbox" name="xinfo" class="toggle" id="toggle1"/>
     <div class="fold">Element 1</div>
    </aside>

    <aside class="folder">
     <input type="checkbox" name="xinfo" class="toggle" id="toggle2"/>
     <div class="fold">Element 2</div>
    </aside>
    
    <aside class="folder">
     <input type="checkbox" name="xinfo" class="toggle" id="toggle3"/>
    </aside>
   </div>
```

Comment: You can not "de-select" a radio button explicitly, it happens only implicitly when another one in the same group gets checked.

Comment: That I know, that's why I'm looking for a solution or another way to do this. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: The solution is contained in what you know already. If you have X radio buttons and you want to be able to “de-select” them - then you add an additional radio button that belongs to the same group. So wherever you want to put that functionality of “de-selecting all”, you put a label that targets that radio button.

Comment: If you change the type from checkbox to radio and select radio toggle 3 that has nothing inside, it will actually close the others and display nothing, which is actually what I need. It would only be better if you could click on the radio that is open to close it again instead of using a 'close all' button/radio.
(Does somebody know the official or most used name for what I'm trying to create?)

Comment: Then place a label in the place where you want to click to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found till now is to use radio. You need to use 1 extra input that has no content, so it will not show when you select it. This way the other ones will close.

```
<aside class="folder">
  <input type="radio" name="xinfo" class="toggle" id="toggle3"/>
</aside>
```

JSFiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/zv1pd6wn/

The only problem now is that the close button will be visible till the end of the animation, I already tried to solve it, but no luck, help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Is this you want. kindly try below code.

```
   <label for="toggle1" class="toggle-label">FOLD/UNFOLD</label>
            <label for="toggle2" class="toggle-label">FOLD/UNFOLD</label>
            <label for="toggle3" class="toggle-label">CLOSE</label>
      <input type="radio" name="xinfo" class="toggle" id="toggle3"/>

    
            <div class="content">
                <aside class="folder">
                    <input type="radio" name="xinfo" class="toggle" id="toggle1"/>
                    <div class="fold">Element 1</div>
                </aside>

                <aside class="folder">
                    <input type="radio" name="xinfo" class="toggle" id="toggle2"/>
                    <div class="fold">Element 2</div>
                </aside>
                
            </div>



   --css---

    .folder {
        width: 100%;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .fold {
        visibility: hidden;
        background-color: #8b0000;
        width: 60%;
        height: 0px;
        color: transparent;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
        transition: all 0.3s;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .toggle { display: none; }

    .toggle-label {
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #999;
        background-color: #8b0000;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .toggle-label:hover {
        background-color: #400000;
    }

    .toggle:checked ~ .fold {
        height: 80px;
        visibility: visible;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .content{
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 0;
        position: static;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .toggle:checked ~ .content {
        min-height: 80px;
    }
    
    
    #toggle3:checked + .content .fold
    {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Don't put junk in a code block to hack around the requirement to put the answer in the answer instead of just linking to JS Fiddle.

Comment: @Quentin. I didn't post permanent link . That is just for quick view for him.

Comment: why people are down voting my post. I didn't post wrong or irrelevant answer.

Comment: It's a badly formatted lump of code that is completely free of anything resembling an explanation about how it works, what is changed from the code in the question, or why that should make a difference.

Comment: @Matti VM , At two place I changed the code one HTML and other in CSS. You just do copy-paste and check whether is it fine or not?

Comment: @Quentin. I'm new, but there is no need to be rude, I'm happy he tried to give me a good answer.
Amit1992, I'm sorry, but the code didn't actually help or even changed something. But thanks for helping!

Comment: @MattiVM — You seem to be confusing criticism with rudeness. While they might have tried to give a good answer, they utterly failed and ended up clogging up the page with something unhelpful.